# How do I check if an id is 'active'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have buttons that change color when selected or when "active". Each button holds information to do calculations but when one of the buttons is pressed I need to make a box that holds one of the outputs null. I believe the easiest way to do it would be to place this in my calculations code:

```
if "button id" is "active"
set value to null
```

I do not know how to translate that english into javascript.
The ids are what I am giving the CSS ".active" attribute to. Fairly new to the stack overflow thing so if this does not make sense or more information is needed please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well to start with, you need to build selectors. The most generic is `document.querySelectorAll`. I haven't tested it but I think `document.querySelectorAll("button[active=\"true\"]")` should be pretty close to what you need. If you provide some sample markup, we can make a JSFiddle and solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the CSS .active attribute' - is it a class you are giving the elements or an attribute?

Comment: btw a `button` element naturally can be _**active**_, _**focus**ed_ and _**hover**ed_. Something like being _**selected**_ or _**checked**_ are features of option lists and radio/checkbox controls. Pointing to that, the Qs are, how does the OP's code base look like, what is the expected behavior and what did the OP already try?

Comment: I was writing a solution but question is closed :D 

I think I figure out your problem. Try to open new question and add more details. 
Tag my nickname to comment section I will paste it.

I can past answer here because someone closed your question unfortunately. :(

Comment: @muhammedoğuz ... The OP should feel encouraged to edit the Q here. The details which are missing are part of the editing process. If provided thoughtfully chances are very high, that the Q gets opened for answers again. Thus it's not a good advice to just drop the same problem wrapped into a new question again at SO.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You're right. Improving question is better approach. But I think OP's should be more patient when new ones post a Q. I know there are a lat of non providing code questions but this is a general questions with general problem. So I think question is clear in this case.

Comment: ' document.querySelector("#product3[active=\"true\"]") ' this worked for me. Doesn't cooperate with my code but does make it all the way through my decision structures meaning it does work @h0r53

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating more in my question. There wasn't really any errors or anything else I tried to implement because I lacked the knowledge to do so. Hence the question in the first place. I appreciate everyone's interaction and input on my question

Comment: @codeg, that's great! You likely want to store the result of `document.querySelector` in some object so you can operate on it after selecting it. For example, setting the value to `null`.

Comment: @h0r53 awesome thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunc(reed) {
  if (reed.classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementById("demon").innerHTML = "Yes I contain .active";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demon").innerHTML = "No, sorry not having .active";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="notactive" onclick="myfunc(this)">Not active</button>
<button class="Iam active" onclick="myfunc(this)">I am active</button>
<span id="demon"></span>
```